# Feature thumbnails for specific custom post types

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, custom-post-type

Its pretty simple i think, but i dont find anything about it.. i'd like to feature thumbnails for my three post types, i please you guys to help me.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'crew', 'staff' , 'guest') );

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'crew',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Crew' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Crew' )),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'crew')
    )
);

register_post_type( 'staff',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Staff' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Staff' )),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'staff')
    )
);

register_post_type( 'guest',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Gast' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Gast' )),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'guest')
    )
);
}
```

I think there is not realy more to say, it's probably very very simple for you guys....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the support for feature images, so add the following line after each array for all the custom post types.

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'sticky')
```

You can of course remove or add the features you need or don't. See all supports in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

Comment: Thanks a lot! Absolutely perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a 'supports' line in each post type so WP knows which features to allow for each one.

Using your example it should look like this to support featured images:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'crew',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Crew' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Crew' )),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'crew')
    ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' )
);

register_post_type( 'staff',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Staff' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Staff' )),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'staff')
    ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' )
);

register_post_type( 'guest',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Gast' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Gast' )),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'guest')
    ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' )
);
}
```

Remove this line:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'crew', 'staff' , 'guest') );
```